# Kernel density estimates comparison in a multivariate setting

Tags: kernel-smoothing, density-estimation, generative-models

I have a dataset with 64 features and binary labels (class 1 and class 2). Before I fit any classification models, I wanted to check whether the samples belonging to the two classes come from the same distribution or from different ones? Class 1 had $~14000$ samples and class 2 had around $17000$ samples.  I adopted the following approach:

- Derive the KDE estimates for both classes. I selected the bandwidth parameter using Gridsearch in Python. I use the [KernelDensity() from sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity)
- Now I have two arrays each of length equal to the number of samples for each class.The arrays have the log probability densities for each sample.
- My question is, how do I compare the KDE estimates (log-prob densities) between the two classes. I was going through a method called KL divergence, but KL divergence is for same sized samples. I don't have that. Can I do a simple KS test?
- How about visual representation? I constructed the violin plots for both the estimate arrays derived from step 1. They look pretty different. Does that mean the class distributions are dissimilar?
  Is there any robust statistical test that would tell me the difference betwene the two distributions and also assign a significance value to that result.

Edit: The violoin plots for the log densities for each class is shown below. 
[image]

Comment: If you have separation on one variable, the distributions are different, so your last bullet point, to me, says that you have distinct distributions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So I have updated the post with the violin plot for the two classes. One thing that struck me was they are of different range. Do I need to normalize it and then plot? Also, how do I quantify the difference between the two?